# from tensorflow.core.example import example_pb2

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand the tensorflow source. I find the line

`from tensorflow.core.example import example_pb2`

in several examples. Yet if I go to that directory in tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ i cannot comprehend where example_pb2 is supposed to be defined. Would be thankful for any hints.

Comment: I'm running linux, and this file is located at `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/core/example/example_pb2.py`

Comment: Thanks I guess it is created during installation, as in the source i couldnt find but indeed i found it in one of my machine's tensorflow directories